# Angular template variable used to disable button throws compile error

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am trying to use Angular template variables to pass values to a button that calls the backend. When I compile the code below I get an error. Why is the angular template throwing an error? I used an example from the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables

I assumed it might be because:

> The structural directive, *ngFor instantiates the template twice because *ngFor iterates over the two items in the array. It is impossible to define what the ref.value reference signifies.

however I dont understand it.... wouldn't the selected option be the one that is instantiated? And if its not instantiated wouldn't it be undefined?

```
ERROR in src/app/statusview/statusview.component.html:84:96 - error TS2339: Property 'endo' does not exist on type 'StatusviewComponent'.

84                         <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="ReloadOdataEndpoint(endo.value)"
```

Code

```
                <select>
                    <option *ngFor="let t of selectedCustomer.endpoints" #endo [ngValue]="t.name">
                        {{t.name}}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="ReloadEndpoint(endo.value)"
                    disabled="!endo" style="margin: 5px;">
                    Load Endpoint
                </button>
```

**Note:** None of these vars are declared in the template- im trying to set them in html and pass them in the template

Comment: Like the error suggests, do you have a property called `endo` in your component class?

Comment: endo is initialised by the template as he shows, you need to set your #endo to the select-element instead of the options

Comment: @Rilcon42 shouldn't template variable be set to select, not option.. you basically want to get selected option value.

Comment: @ulmas I do not have the endo property declared in the component. I am trying to declare it in the HTML and pass it into the component when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference an option element, you will have one reference for multiple elements.
Put it on the select and pick the value.

```
<select #endo>
  <option *ngFor="let t of selectedCustomer.endpoints" [ngValue]="t.name">
   {{t.name}}
  </option>
</select>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="ReloadEndpoint(endo.value)" disabled="!endo" style="margin: 5px;">
 Load Endpoint
</button>
```